# Remove the Name from a WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application, I want to allow the user to load several arbitrary XAML files. Internally, I use `XamlReader.Load()` to load the XAML.

Now, it may happen that some of the XAMLs have named controls, such as

```
<Button Name="button" ... />
```

If the user accidentally loads 2 XAMLs that define the same name, an exception occurs, saying

> Could not register named object. Cannot register duplicate name "button" in this scope.

So my next step was to unregister all names before loading the XAML:

```
foreach (FrameworkElement child in ((Grid) Content).Children)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(child.Name))
    {
        UnregisterName(child.Name);
    }
}
```

However, that's not sufficient, I still can't load the XAML for the same reason.

**How do I get rid of the name of a control?**

Note: while doing research on this, I found many answers for the question "How do I remove a control by its name?". That's not what I want. I want to keep the control, but un-name it.

Note: I'm not looking for workarounds. I know that I could e.g. process the XAML as plain XML, remove the names and then load it. I'd really like to know whether and how it's possible to do that in a WPF way.

I have also tried:

- change the name with `child.Name = null;`
- changing the scope with `NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());`
- combinations of the above

Comment: I cannot repro this. If I don’t call RegisterName, the control ‘s Name property is null even though it has a value in the XAML string and so it can be loaded/added again to the Grid without throwing the exception. So you should have called RegisterName, right?

Comment: @kennyzx: Indeed, you're right. It causes a conflict with one of the buttons I have on my form, not between buttons of the XAML I load. I need to update my question.